# Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible monic. When will $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f\rangle$ be integrally closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible monic, and I want some criterion to determine when $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f\rangle$ will be integrally closed. Since $A$ is Noetherian and $\dim A=1$, it suffices to show that $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a DVR for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}\in\operatorname{Spec} A$, but any such ideal must be of the form $\langle p,g\rangle$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime, and $g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is such that $\overline{g}\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible, so that it is necessary and sufficient to prove that $$\big(\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f\rangle\big)_{\langle p,g\rangle} = \left(\mathbb{Z}[x]_{\langle p,g\rangle}\right)\!\!\big/\langle f\rangle$$ is principal.

However, I see no easy criterion for checking if this is true. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: with $p$ prime and $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ irreducible $\bmod p$, then $\langle p,g \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so that : $f \in \langle p,g \rangle$ (ie $f \equiv g \bmod p$) or $\langle p,g, f \rangle = \langle 1\rangle$ ?

Comment: Essentially you're asking when the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ is equal to $A$. There is a simple sufficient condition (the discriminant of $f$ being squarefree) but as far as I know there is no easy necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Well, we require that $\langle f\rangle\subset\langle p,g\rangle$, which is equivalent to requiring that $f\in\langle p,g\rangle$, which implies that $\overline{g}\mid\overline{f}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ (since $\overline{f}\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ need not be irreducible, your statement may not be true).

Comment: What is the proof that it is sufficient that the discriminant of $f$ be square-free?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$, let $\Delta_K$ be its discriminant, and let $d$ be the index of $A$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then $\Delta(f)=d^2\Delta_K$. In particular, if $\Delta(f)$ is squarefree then $d=1$.

Comment: So I guess having $\Delta(f)=\Delta_K$ is necessary and sufficient, but in practice computing $\Delta_K$ requires knowing a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ already.